# How did Homer describe Mycenae?

Tags: greek, myth-identification

Did he link his description with myth of Perseus? Could we imagine how it looks like ?

Answer (score 4):

About your first question, there are no mentions of that Perseus in the *Odyssey*, but of another Perseus that was son of Nestor and Eurydice (or Anaxibia).

And in the *Iliad* there's no link of Perseus with Mycenae, but there it is with Argos:

> and swiftly came to Achaean Argos, where she knew was the stately wife
>   of Sthenelus, son of Perseus, that bare a son in her womb, and lo, the
>   seventh month was come. This child Hera brought forth to the light
>   even before the full tale of the months, but stayed Alcmene's bearing,
>   and held back the Eileithyiae. And herself spake to Zeus, son of
>   Cronos, to bear him word: ‘Father Zeus, lord of the bright lightning,
>   a word will I speak for thy heeding. Lo, even now, is born a valiant
>   man that shall be lord over the Argives, even Eurystheus, son of
>   Sthenelus, the son of Perseus, of thine own lineage; not unmeet is it
>   that he be lord over the Argives.’

<sup>[Hom. Il. 19.115](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.01.0134:book=19:card=114&highlight=perseus)</sup>

"Argives" could be used as an epithet for the whole Greeks, but Homer mentions "Achaean Argos".

About your second question, searching "Mycenae" in the *Iliad* brings [five results](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/searchresults?target=en&inContent=true&q=Mycenae&doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0134) in the Perseus site (for a total of seven mentions). An extra one if you search for "Mycene".

In my opinion, these two are the only relevant results for your question:

> And with them came a third, Euryalus, a godlike warrior, son of king
>   Mecisteus, son of Talaus; but leader over them all was Diomedes, good
>   at the war-cry. And with these there followed eighty black ships. And
>   they that held **Mycenae, the well-built citadel**, and wealthy
>   Corinth, and well-built Cleonae, and dwelt in Orneiae and lovely
>   Araethyrea and Sicyon, wherein at the first Adrastus was king; and
>   they that held Hyperesia and steep Gonoessa and Pellene

<sup>[Hom. Il. 2.565](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.01.0134:book=2:card=546&highlight=mycenae)</sup>

> Then in answer to him spake ox-eyed, queenly Hera: “Verily have I three
>   cities that are far dearest in my sight, Argos and Sparta and
>   **broad-wayed Mycenae**; these do thou lay waste whensoe'er they shall be
>   hateful to thy heart. Not in their defence do I stand forth, nor
>   account them too greatly.

<sup>[Hom. Il. 4.50](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.01.0134:book=4:card=50&highlight=mycenae)</sup>

Also, Agamemnon is sometimes referred to as "king of Mycenae, rich in gold", and the only mention of Mycenae in the *Odyssey* is this one:

> Seven years he reigned over **Mycenae, rich in gold**, after slaying
>   the son of Atreus, and the people were subdued under him; but in the
>   eighth came as his bane the goodly Orestes back from Athens, and slew
>   his father's murderer.

<sup>[Hom. Od. 3.305](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.01.0136:book=3:card=276&highlight=mycenae)</sup>

So with these three things we can make from Homer that Mycenae was a well-built citadel, made of broad streets, and very rich in gold.